# Search All Files in a Website

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am working on a project in which I need to find all files in a website. For example my webpage contains index.html and a PDF file.
How others can find out that there is a PDF file in my website domain?

Comment: http://www.httrack.com/ will make a copy of a web site - i.e. anything that can be found from http://yoursite.com

Comment: as @EdHeal suggested, it is possible with httrack.com

Comment: Also good for finding broken links!

Answer (score 0):

You need a scraper of some sort.
ex) http://scrapy.org/

You can traverse a webpage by their links.

If you think of a page as a node and link as children
you can easily cover all files of that website.

If that specific website shows every link in its pages,
this method is possible, if not then you have to use
other means such as search engine to look through it's indexed pages.